# Android Service not calling unbindService()

Tags: android, service

I learned that you can start [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) by calling [bindService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int)) and call [unbindService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unbindService(android.content.ServiceConnection)) to stop it. What happens if I call `bindService()` from an activity to start a background service, and close (destroy) that activity without calling `unbindService()`?

Will the boundService survive? I'm trying to start a background task and stop it only when I tell it to later. This could be after the activity that started it is closed and opened again sometime later.

Comment: "Will the boundService survive?" -- it shouldn't. "I'm trying to start a background task and stop it only when I tell it to later" -- then use `startService()`.

Comment: If I need to talk to that service like a client-server, should I **both** start and bind the service? So I would bind and unbind with the activity life cycle, and also start and stop the service manually.

Comment: That is certainly possible.